# Featured Story Shortcode not outputting content

Tags: posts, categories, shortcode

So I'm trying to get a shortcode working where it calls the posts in the featured story category but I'm having issue getting it to output even just the title from the post. There's no error on the page. But there's nothing else showing either but white space between the nav and footer.

```
function featured_story() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category_name' => 'featured_story'
    ); 

    $last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) :
        $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();

        $content .= '<div class="featured-stories">';
        $content .= '<h3>' .$title. '</h3>';

    endwhile;

return $content;

}
add_shortcode( 'featured-story', 'featured_story' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing :
initialize variable $content=''; before the while loop.
other than that your code is right. there is something you are doing wrong to use shortcode. you should check this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/#user-contributed-notes
and make changes.

also if using for custom post type please add post_type argument in $args

Comment: How is it mostly right except for one thing but yet also wrong and do_shortcode needs to be inputted to replace something else? Mind elaborating a bit on that please? I'm not exactly getting on my own from the link

Comment: let me know where are you putting this shortcode?
Okay so I just tested this code and its really working for the default post type with same category name the only differece was in category slug by default it was created with slug featured-story (used as 'category_name' => 'featured_story' ) but its not big deal.
on the other hand i tested in template file. as : ** echo do_shortcode( '[featured-story]' ); **

Comment: function featured_story(){
    $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category_name' => 'featured-story'
    ); 
    $last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// print_r($last_5_posts_query);
    $content = '';
    while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) :
        $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $content .= '<div class="featured-stories">';
        $content .= '<h3>' .$title. '</h3>';

    endwhile;

    return $content;

}

Comment: Well, thank you so much for the help! That definitely helped get it working with the changes of initializing the variable and changing 'featured_story' to 'featured-story'.